# How to define the number of columns in a table with XMLWorker?

Tags: html, pdf, itext

I am using `XMLWorker` so I am not able to create columns using `PdfPTable`. Is it possible using iText to give the number of columns by default? Right now it's giving me just one column as I am using `XMLWorker.parse()` function.

Comment: So you're parsing HTML with a table in it? Does the HTML not have the correct number of columns? Also, have you run your HTML through a validator?